# 91 Chevy Suburban won't start

Tags: starting, chevrolet, suburban

My Suburban will not start. I have tried replacing plugs ignition control module (ICM), all the controls on the carb. I can hear the fuel pump and installed new injectors. Will this obd2 scanner tool help me to locate the issue? What do you think is going on? I'm fixing myself.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It sounds like you're just throwing parts at the issue. Your vehicle is an OBD1 vehicle, so unless the OBD2 scanner also reads those codes, it won't help you.

Comment: Also, have you checked to ensure the plugs are firing? If so, have you tried firing some ether, starting fluid, or even brake cleaner down the throttle body to see if it will start or at least come to life that way?

Comment: Those years are prone to the pick up coil inside the distributor failing. You can either replace the pick up coil (requires removal and disassembly of the distributor), or buy a new dist off of ebay or amazon.